# Can we construct reduced group scheme which is same group structure given an abstract group?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, group-schemes

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $G$ be an abstract group (if necessary finite),
and $k$ be an algebraically closed field.

Now is there  a group scheme $X$ over $k$ such that group of $k$-valued point $X(k)=\operatorname {Hom}_k(\operatorname {Spec} k, X)$ is isomorphic to $G$?

Especially when $G$ is finite, is there such X as reduced?

(I mean "scheme over $k$" as separated finite type  over $k$.)

Comment: You can just take the constant group scheme, but maybe that’s not what you’re after.

Comment: Take $G$ many copies of $\operatorname{Spec} k$. If $G$ is finite then this will be a separated reduced scheme of finite type over $k$; in general it will be separated and reduced but only locally of finite type.

Comment: @Nakayama - You may check explicitly in simple examples that if $G$ is a finite group and $\Gamma(G)$ the constant group scheme of $G$ (over a field $k$) it follows the $k$-rational points $\Gamma(G)(k) \cong G$ recover $G$. As an example try $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$

Comment: the constant group scheme has $A:=k\{e_g: g\in G\}$ as algebra (direct sum of copies of $k$, one for each $g\in G$ and $\Delta: A \rightarrow A\otimes_k A$ defined by $\Delta(e_g):= \sum_{g=\sigma\tau} e_{\sigma}\otimes e_{\tau}$. It follows $Spec(A)(k) \cong G$ as groups.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "Can we construct reduced group scheme which is same group structure given an abstract group?"

**Answer:** As mentioned in the comments: You may check explicitly in simple examples that if $G$ is a finite group and $Γ(G)$ the constant group scheme of $G$ (over a field $k$) it follows the $k$-rational points $Γ(G)(k)≅G$ recover $G$. As an example try $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$. The constant group scheme has $A:=k\{e_g:g∈G\}$ as algebra (direct sum of copies of $k$, one for each $g∈G$ and $Δ:A→A⊗_k A$ defined by $Δ(e_g):=∑_{g=στ} e_σ⊗e_τ$. It follows there is an isomorphism $\Gamma(G)(k):=Spec(A)(k)≅G$ as groups. The group scheme $\Gamma(G)$ is reduced: The ring $A$ is a direct product of fields and is reduced.

**Note:** A group scheme in this sense is a representable functor

$$h_{\Gamma(G)}: \underline{k-alg} \rightarrow \underline{Groups}$$

meaning the induced functor $h_{\Gamma(G)}: \underline{k-alg} \rightarrow \underline{Sets}$ is representable. Its $k$-rational points $\Gamma(G)(k):=Hom_{k-alg}(A,k)$ is therefore canonically a (finite) group, isomorphic to the original group $G$.

**Note:** The category $\underline{k-alg}$ is not a small category. You may also consider the affine scheme $\Gamma(G):=Spec(A)$. This scheme has a multiplication operation $m$ and an inversion $i$, and the triple $(\Gamma(G), m,i)$ is a group scheme in the "naive" sense. Here "naive" means you work with $((\Gamma(G), \mathcal{O}_{\Gamma(G)}), m,i)$ as a locally ringed space with two morphisms $m,i$, instead of working with the associated functor of points $h_{\Gamma(G)}$.